# SSL Authentication Explanation

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I know little bit about certificates but not in details. I am asked to install **.CER** certificate in an android app, I saw currently app uses three files(see below). I am confused how just one CER file will used for authentication/identification if currently system is using multiple files.
I tried to look online but did not find good explanation of how these files work together for authentication/identification. I am sure I need same set of new files and only CER file will not be suffice, its just I don't know the relation between these files and how these files used by system. 
If you can point me to some good online resource that would be great help.

```
cacert.file=ca.cert.pem
cert.file=client.cert.pem
key.file=client.key.pem
```

Comment: This is probably just SSL client authentication, you can use your favorite search engine to search for " SSL client authentication in XYZ", substituting your preferred language/platform for XYZ.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you don't understand. But in short: the certificate is the public visible part (like a passport) and the key is the secret on how you can digitally prove that this the certificate belongs to you (i.e. only you know the secret). Read about [Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) for more. What the cacert is for in your case is not clear since the content is unknown but it might be the chain of certificates leading to a trusted issuer - see [Chain of trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust).